# Hide or show menu bar on scrolling

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I got to animate a div when `$('body').scrollTop() > 45`

I need animate the same div when the user scrolls up. I tried this code, the first **if** works. How can I get the second **conditional** to work?

```
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > 45) {

        $('.my-div').animate({
            top:'-45px'
        }, 200);
    }         
    if (¿?user-scrolls-up¿?) {

        $('.my-div').animate({
            top:'0px'
        }, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Save the scroll value to a variable on scroll. Compare to the previous scroll value. If previous > current then user has scrolled up. Or you could use a `setInterval`, comparing the last iteration intervals' scroll position to the current iteration

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide a Div when the scroll bar is moving with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390960/how-to-hide-a-div-when-the-scroll-bar-is-moving-with-jquery)

Comment: @ZachSaucier thanks, got it working based in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to save the scroll value to a variable on scroll. Then you can compare that value to the previous scroll value. If previous > current then user has scrolled up.

Here is pseduo-code for that situation

```
var lastScroll = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    ... Your first if perhaps using currentScroll ...
    if(currentScroll < lastScroll) {
        $('.my-div').animate({
            top:'0px'
        }, 200);
    }
    lastScroll = currentScroll;
}
```

Or you could use a `setInterval`, comparing the last iteration intervals' scroll position to the current iteration