# Hide a div on scroll but keep it visible when active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to hide the `.site-header` on scroll and have it re-appear after inactivity for a couple of seconds.

I found the most of the answer here: [How to hide a Div when the scroll bar is moving with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390960/how-to-hide-a-div-when-the-scroll-bar-is-moving-with-jquery)

```js
    var $header = $(".site-header");
    var opacity = $header.css("opacity");
    var scrollStopped;

    var fadeInCallback = function () {
        if (typeof scrollStopped != 'undefined') {
            clearInterval(scrollStopped);
        }

        scrollStopped = setTimeout(function () {
            $header.animate({ opacity: 1 }, "slow");
        }, 500);
    }

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (!$header.is(":animated") && opacity == 1) {
            $header.animate({ opacity: 0 }, "slow", fadeInCallback);
        } else {
            fadeInCallback.call(this);
        }
    });

    $('.menu-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.menu-toggle').addClass('activated');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section style="height:5000px;">
    <div class="site-header" style="position:fixed; top:5px; left:5px; width:200px; height:100px; display:block; background:#000; opacity:1;">
        
        <button class="menu-toggle">Menu</button>

        <nav class="nav-primary">
            <ul>
            <li>Menu item 1</li>
            <li>Menu item 2</li>
            <li>Menu item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>

</section>
```

The `nav` is activated by clicking `button`

However, the `nav` is nested inside the `.site-header` which means when the menu is activated it still fades out on scroll...

I'm wondering how to alter this javascript so that when the `.activated` class is applied to the `button` the `nav` remains visible even while scrolling.

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fwa16eok/

Thanks so much!

Comment: You can use `.hasClass("activated")` to check if the class is applied.

Comment: @ChrisG How do I do that in the context of the above code? Sorry, I'm not too well versed with JS so not sure where exactly to put that...I've updated my question with more specific code and the Fiddle

Comment: Where it says `!$header.is(":animated") && opacity == 1`, append `&& !$header.hasClass("activated")`, this should prevent the fade out if the class is applied.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div>
   <div class="a">A</div>
</div>​
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {  
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $('.a').fadeOut();  } 
   else {
      $('.a').fadeIn();
 }
});
```

Comment: This isn't about the scroll position at all.

Comment: Actually you wanted to hide the div when you scrolling the page ryt?

Comment: I want to hide the div when scrolling. But keep it visible when the `.activated` class is applied to the `button`

Answer (score 0):

Add `!$menu.is(":active")` before the fade out animation call

```js
var $menu = $("#menu");
    var opacity = $menu.css("opacity");
    var scrollStopped;

    var fadeInCallback = function () {
        if (typeof scrollStopped != 'undefined') {
            clearInterval(scrollStopped);
        }

        scrollStopped = setTimeout(function () {
            $menu.animate({ opacity: 1 }, "slow");
        }, 2000);
    }

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (!$menu.is(":active") &&!$menu.is(":animated") && opacity == 1) {
            $menu.animate({ opacity: 0 }, "slow", fadeInCallback);
        } else {
            fadeInCallback.call(this);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section style="height:5000px;">
    <div id="menu" style="position:fixed; top:5px; left:5px; width:200px; height:100px; display:block; background:#000; opacity:1;"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: this still fades on scroll...I have updated the code and fiddle on my question to be more specific. Does that help?

Comment: it wont fade when its active, try to click on it while scrolling

Comment: for it to be `active` you should click while scrolling(don't leave the click)